# MySQL result to array VB.NET

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, vb.net

I am creating a program in VB.NET which uses an online MySQL database to retrieve certain data. I have now succeeded in connecting and getting some basic stuff out of it. Now, what I want to do is that when an user presses a button it has to update the list. What happens is that the stuff that is already in the database also gets resent and so the list just doubles himself, although it adds the new database value.

How can I make sure that it only adds new values to the list, instead of adding all values from the list again? I have read that you can use the `Preserve` keyword with arrays, though this isn't an array and neither have I figured out how to convert my data into an array.

```vb
Private Sub generateList()
    DB.writeQuery("SELECT snacks.ID, snacks.naam, snacks.baktijd FROM snacks")

    While DB.DR.Read
        ListBox1.Items.Add(DB.DR.Item("naam"))
    End While

    DB.closeConnection()
End Sub
```

This is the piece of code I use to generate the list, I reuse this code to refresh the list. As you can see, it uses my own written MySQL class. I know it makes an connection so there is nothing wrong with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *“As you can see, it uses my own written MySQL class”* Avoid doing that. Plus it’s hard to answer questions if we don’t know how your own class works. Anyways, yes, use `ListBox1.Items.Clear()`, and make sure to call `ListBox1.BeginUpdate()` before clearing and `ListBox1.EndUpdate()` at the end of `generateList()`.

Comment: Also, rather than doing the grunt work yourself and writing a new class to access the database, there are data access layer classes out there already that handle that part for you.  Here is a link to one of them: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158042/DALC-NET-A-Generic-Data-Access-Layer-for-NET

Comment: Thanks to both. I know it is much easier, and probably a lot safer, to use a class which has already been written and proven itselfs in the past. I thought it would be good practice to write a class myself as I just finished the tutorials. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will want to do is to clear the `ListBox` before you reload the list.  You can do this like so:

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
```

Then when you reload the list, the items will not be duplicated.

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that! Now I remember I learned this in one of the 200 tutorials I have watched. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to clear your listbox before adding the items.

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
 If Not listBox1.Items.Contains(DB.DR.Item("naam")) Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(DB.DR.Item("naam"))
    else
    'this item already exists.
    end if
```